# How to use a variable included in a layout in posts using that layout?

Tags: jekyll

Consider the following three snippets from the specified files:

```
<!-- _includes/my_var.html -->
{% assign my_var = 'foo' %}
```

and

```
<!-- _layouts/default.html -->
{% include my_var.html %}
...
```

and a post:

```
---
layout: default
---
I'd like to reference {{my_var}}
```

The last one doesn't appear to see the variable defined in the includes file. I get `nil` as the value of `my_var`. Am I wrong to expect that it should be in scope? If so, what's an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get layout variables from page or post.

But, as it looks like a configuration variable, you can set it in *_config.yml* and access it from anywhere with `site.my_var`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with frontmatter as well.

```
---
layout: default
myvar: foo
---
I'd like to reference {{page.myvar}} OR
I'd like to reference {{post.myvar}}
```